# WebStorm : Jsdoc unresolved function or method for console.debug()

Tags: javascript, webstorm, jsdoc3

I am getting this error on WebStorm "Unresolved function or method" while implementing console.debug(). 
I have already added the HTML, HTML 5 in Settings->Languages & Framework->Javascript-> Libraries.
Any leads will be helpful.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please attach a code sample with your JSDoc. Thanks!

Comment: /**
* @class ChatPage
*/
console.debug('Chat loading... ');

var ChatPage = SomeFunction({
});

Answer (score 0):

This happens because WebStorm doesn't have `console.debug` definition in it's internal file DHTML.js, like `console.log`.

It will be fixed in WebStorm 2016.3. Tracking issue is [WEB-3371](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-3371).